# Two Morse functions that are equal at their critical points

Tags: differential-topology, morse-theory

$f,g$ are Morse functions from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$ such that if $(x,y)$ is a critical point of $f$ or if $(x,y)$ is a critical point of $g$ implies $f(x,y)=g(x,y)$.

Can we say that $f$ and $g$ must have the same set of critical points?

Context and what I've tried:

I've asked myself this question while studying Morse theory. When $f$ and $g$ are one dimensional variable it's trivial, in two dimensions the problem is way more tricky, so I was looking for some reference as it seems a basic question.

EDIT: I've realized we need to add the hypotesis that the functions stable and unstable manifolds are bounded.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following counterexample:
$$\color{blue}{f(x,y) = (x^2-1)^2+y^2}$$
$$\color{green}{g(x,y) = 1-x^2-y^2}$$
with influencing lower dimensional case (left). One can see the sets of critical points are different, though both functions agree over the union of critical points.
It remains to be shown that these are Morse functions.

[image]

---

$$det(H_f) = (\partial_{xx}\partial_{yy} - \partial_{xy}^2)f = 8(3x^2-1).$$
$$det(H_g) = (\partial_{xx}\partial_{yy} - \partial_{xy}^2)g = 4.$$
Since the critical points occur at $\{(0,0),(\pm 1,0)\}$ these are nonzero. $[\times]$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've added in the EDIT that the functions must have bounded stable and unstable manifolds, this example is possible because after the "missed" critical point one or both the functions escape to infinity without "encounter" any other critical points.

Comment: Do you mean the surfaces they generate must be bounded?

Comment: If we consider the dinamical system on R^2 associated to the gradient flow given by -grad f, every critical point of f is an equilibrium point. The stable manifold of a local maxima is the region of the plane attracted by the maxima itself, in a similar way we can define the unstable manifolds around a local minima.

Comment: Is it possible for both stable and unstable manifolds to be bounded simultaneously? Why do you want to add this requirement. I think the question needs to be updated with more background

Comment: Is it possible if the fuction has an infinite number of critical points, like a cosine function. I think the question is pretty natural in the context of morse theory, where usually a morse function is used to study the topology of the underlying manifolds, and usually is done on compact manifold where it can be shown some invariances. My question simplify a bit the context asking just for the plane, but I need to add the compactness request as the plane is not compact for itself, and the quesiton boils down to ask if the critical  values practically characterize the morse function.